# preg_replace few chars between two tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
this is text before the tag \r \t
    \begin{aligned}\t \r \r
    \left(\frac{130}{100}x\right)  \t
    \end{aligned}
this is text after the tag \r \t
```

I want to delete all occurances of `\r`, `\t` and `\n` between the `\begin` and `\end` . How can I do it using `preg_replace`.

Comment: Are the `\t`, `\r` and `\n` literal, or they represent some special characters?

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200353/match-line-break-with-regular-expression

Comment: \t, \r and \n  are getting generated after json encode, i want to remove them only if above type of equation come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the OP's clarification, here, the `\r`, `\n` and `\t` are literals, and shouldn't be confused with the corresponding special characters.

```
<?php
$str = <<<'EOT'
this is text before the tag \r \t
    \begin{aligned}\t \r \r
    \left(\frac{130}{100}x\right)  \t
    \end{aligned}
this is text after the tag \r \t
\begin another \r\n\t\end
EOT;

echo
    '<pre>' .
    preg_replace_callback(
        '#\\\\begin.*?\\\\end#s', // The regular expression
        function ($matches) {
            return str_replace(array('\t', '\r', '\n'), '', $matches[0]); // removes all the specified literals
        },
        $str
    ) .
    '</pre>';
?>
```

The regular expression in the `preg_replace_callback()` matches all the text between the `\begin` and `\end` strings (inclusive). Having the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in the pattern causes the [dot metacharacter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) not to exclude the new line characters.

For every match found, the function calls the anonymous function specified in the second argument, which removes the literals using a call to the `str_replace()` function.

Output:

```
this is text before the tag \r \t
    \begin{aligned}  
    \left(\frac{130}{100}xight)  
    \end{aligned}
this is text after the tag \r \t
\begin another \end
```

Comment: oh ya.. did it.. i was not aware how to do that !

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the `\G` anchors to obtain only contiguous results. When `\end` is reached the contiguity is broken. The first match starts with the branch (1).

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
this is text before the tag \r \t
    \begin{aligned}\t \r \r
    \left(\frac{130}{100}x\right)  \t
    \end{aligned}
this is text after the tag \r \t 
EOD;

$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?:
    \G(?!\A) # other occurrences are contiguous (2)
  |
    \\begin\b # the first occurrence of \t \r or \n follows "\begin" (1)
)
[^\\]* # all that is not a slash
(?:
    \\ (?!(?:[trn]|end)\b) # a slash not followed by "t","r","n" or "end"
    [^\\]*
)* (*SKIP)
\K # remove all characters on the left from the whole match
\\ [trn]
~xS
EOD;

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

You can improve the pattern, if you change `\\begin\b` with `[^\\]*(?:\\(?!begin\b)[^\\]*)*+\\begin\b`