# Javascript: is it possible to console.log hidden chars ('\n, \r')?

Tags: javascript

I have some strings which have line breaks inside, in console they are shown with breaks:

```
string1:
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

I need to split the string and make something like this:

```
string1:
<p>test 1</p>
<p>test 2</p>
<p>test 3</p>
```

For most of them the next code works:

```
string1.split('\n\n').join('</p><p>')
```

but for some strings this doesn't work, so I could assume they have some other line breaks, for example '\r\n'

Can I somehow see all line breaks as they are? I mean as something like the next:

```
string1:
test 1\n\n
test 2\n\n
test 3\n\n
```

Comment: console.log(escape(yourString))

Comment: @epascarello thanks a lot, JSON.stringify is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it only a single newline:

```
test1\ntest2\ntest3
```

Also, you can use replace instead of split-join:

```
string1.replace(/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/g, '</p><p>')
```

Make sure to add on the start and end:

```
'<p>' + string1.replace('\n', '</p><p>') + '</p>'
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't know what chars I should replace .  when I replace \n - it works in most strings
I will try escape as mentioned above, hope this helps

Comment: And that replace line is wrong.... that will only replace one instance

Comment: Oops, I forgot. It should be `string1.replace(/\n/g, '</p><p>')`.

Comment: Still did not answer OP's question.

Comment: Maybe you could check for either newline type (`\n`, `\r`, `\n\r`, or `\r\n`).

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good case for a regular expression. Sometimes line breaks have only \n sometimes \r\n. Have a look at the answer here: [Match line break with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200353/match-line-break-with-regular-expression#answer-5200392) and the documentation on replace() in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace