# One line works but two lines doesn't for regex, why?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the RegEx practice tool to work on some web scraping.

https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html

`(Laboratory Confirmed Cases )([clastexwid\-.\"= h<>\/]+)([0-9]+)/s`
This is what I'm searching for.

These are what I'm searching.

`<td class="text-white">Laboratory Confirmed Cases </td>`

`<td class="text-white">1264450</td>`

If I put the text to be searched on the same line, there is a match. If not then there is no match.

Help?

I'm using Google Apps Script/Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match line break with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200353/match-line-break-with-regular-expression)

Comment: no, they're looking to do something to the end of the first line. I want to include more than one line in my search string.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this article: https://interdigitizer.medium.com/scrape-and-save-data-to-google-sheets-with-apps-script-7e3c0ccec96b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\n?` which indicates that there *might* be a new line.

Something like this could work -

`Laboratory Confirmed Cases <\/td>\n?<td class="text-white">(\d+)<\/td>`

as seen here -

https://regex101.com/r/QBDh57/1

this will return the confirmed case numbers.

or depending on if the text is `trimmed()` or `stripped()` you might need two (\n?\n?) of them.